# Bash shortcut to locate specific character quickly

Tags: bash

I know in `vim` editor, pressing <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> will locate the character `a` and it's a great shortcut for me. But I do not find the similar shortcut in linux `bash` (*emacs mode*).  I use xshell as my terminal.

Comment: Can we know why do you want to do so? To replace misspelt command?

Comment: @IvanChau; Fixing a typing error is one application. Another one may be modifying an already issued command for other arguments. That's what the shell history is for. Selecting single characters, quickly jumping to it is one way to speed up the editing process, other ways are to move word wise, or whatever else the history editor allows to speed up the editing. This is generally useful, but especially if you have very long commands in the history.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use *vi mode* (despite being used to `vi` commands), in *emacs mode* (e.g. in `bash` or `ksh`) there's `Ctrl-]` `c` to find the character `c` on the current history line.

Comment: `Ctrl -]` : search one charactor forward  
`Esc` + `Ctrl-]` : search one character backward  
  
`Ctrl-s` : search string forward in current line but shoud [disable XON/XOFF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791765/unable-to-forward-search-bash-history-similarly-as-with-ctrl-r) first  
`Ctrl-r` : search string backward include history command and current line

Answer (score 2):

The shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> start an incremental search through the history, *including the current command*. So to search for a character going forward, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then the character, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> again. It's more cumbersome than the vi command, but lets you easily search a string and not just a character.